# Stop motor with event trigger - L293D, Pi, Python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I wish to stop a motor with an event trigger.

This is the motor script

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(15,GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

and this is the event trigger script that I wish to incorporate somehow

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 

def button_callback(channel):
    print("Button was pushed!")

GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 

GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.FALLING,callback=button_callback) 

message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n") 

GPIO.cleanup()
```

The idea is that the switch is normally closed when the motor is running. When it opens I want the motor to turn off.

Many thanks!

Comment: See the documentation of [GPIO.event_detected()](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) function.

Comment: @hcheung - Thanks will have a look

Comment: This has now been solved courtesy of a user on the Raspberry Forum - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=224099&p=1373770#p1373770